# Null exception in android while using database

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

I am trying to code much reliably in android so I made different classes for different purposes, like separate class for connection with db, creating tables, and a class for insert update and delete. Now I am getting a problem with SQLiteDatabase [mDb]: I had a class where there are getters and setters for the table columns ie recipient.class. Now I have to insert datas into database so I did such for inserting:

```
public long insert(Recipient recipient, String[] images){
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(FLD_RECIPIENT_ID, Recipient.getFldRecipientId());
        initialValues.put(FLD_INFO, Recipient.getFldInfo());
        initialValues.put(FLD_LATITUDE, Recipient.getFldLatitude());
        initialValues.put(FLD_LONGITUDE, Recipient.getFldLongitude());
        for(int i=0;i<images.length;i++){
            if(images[i]!=null){
                initialValues.put("FLD_IMAGE_URL"+(i+1), images[i]);
            }
        }
        return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }
```

When I debugged all values for initialValues are set and when mDb.insert is performed it exits showing nullPointException and the value for mDb null. I cannot understand why is it so.SO if somebody could help me???
Also I have initialized mDb as:

```
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
```

LOGCAT:

```
01-01 11:11:27.963: E/AndroidRuntime(992): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-01 11:11:27.963: E/AndroidRuntime(992): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-01 11:11:27.963: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at com.example.android.photobyintent.DbReceipient.insert(DbReceipient.java:43)
01-01 11:11:27.963: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at com.example.android.photobyintent.AddRecipient.insertIntoDb(AddRecipient.java:451)
01-01 11:11:27.963: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at com.example.android.photobyintent.AddRecipient$4.onClick(AddRecipient.java:409)
01-01 11:11:27.963: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
01-01 11:11:27.963: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
01-01 11:11:27.963: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-01 11:11:27.963: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-01 11:11:27.963: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-01 11:11:27.963: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-01 11:11:27.963: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-01 11:11:27.963: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-01 11:11:27.963: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-01 11:11:27.963: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-01 11:11:27.963: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Before inserting data using `mDb` just check its **null** or not, If its null then open database in Writable mode.

Comment: `private SQLiteDatabase mDb;` Its a Declaration. Where is definition?

Comment: have u read/write permission in manifest? plz show logcat.

Comment: yes i do i have read/write permission in manifest

Comment: Recipient.getFldRecipientId() no get value print log for check value are came or not..

Comment: @altaf ya the value for recipientId is coming

Comment: no only one all value you should check and image also.. @sid

Answer (score 0):

Do this on the mDB.

```
private SQLiteDatabase mDb = this.getWritableDatabase();
```

Answer (score 0):

initialize `mDb` before inserting in database as:

```
public long insert(Recipient recipient, String[] images){
         mDb = Your_sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();

         // your code here

        return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think mDb is not initialized or its null before you access it.
Try:

before function 
    mDb = this.getWritableDatabase();

```
public long insert(Recipient recipient, String[] images){
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(FLD_RECIPIENT_ID, Recipient.getFldRecipientId());
    initialValues.put(FLD_INFO, Recipient.getFldInfo());
    initialValues.put(FLD_LATITUDE, Recipient.getFldLatitude());
    initialValues.put(FLD_LONGITUDE, Recipient.getFldLongitude());
    for(int i=0;i<images.length;i++){
        if(images[i]!=null){
            initialValues.put("FLD_IMAGE_URL"+(i+1), images[i]);
        }
    }
     if(mdb!=null){
         return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
     }else {
         return null;
     }
}
```

if the return value is null then work accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It's best you use the database object atomically, just open it when you need it and close it as soon as you don't need it anymore

Try like this:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = opener.getWritableDatabase();

    try {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        /* set values */

        return db.insertOrThrow(tableName, null, values);
    } finally {
        db.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `mDb` member variable is not initialized (i.e. it is still `null`) at the time you call the `insert` method.

Where in your class is this variable assigned ? Perhaps you have created another method, named something like `connect`, that you forgot to call before `insert` ?

You need to show more of the code of your class before I can help any further.